# how get multiple checkbox value from session variable

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

In my case i am getting only last checkbox value not showing all checked checkbox value .
there are three pages, 
In menu.php i get multiple checkbox value  from user

```
<form method="POST" action="internal.php">

  <input type="checkbox" name="sides[]" value="Cheese" ><label>Cheese </label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="sides[]" value="Broccoli"><label>Broccoli </label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="sides[]" value="Carrots"><label>Carrots</label>
</form>
```

internal.php (here i store multiple checkbox value in session.)

```
<?php
  session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['sides'])) {
       foreach($_POST['sides'] as $check) {

        $_SESSION['sides']=$check;
         echo $_SESSION['sides']; // if i don't use header location then here i get all checkbox value
         echo "<br>";

      }
  }
 header('location: show.php');
?>
```

and last page i.e show.php i trying to show multiple checkbox value

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['sides'])){ ?>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <p><?php echo $_SESSION['sides']; ?></p> // here i get only last checked checkbox value
  </div>

  <?php unset($_SESSION['sides']); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually saving all the checkbox values in the session, you are only saving the last one as this line

```
$_SESSION['sides']=$check;
```

overwrites `$_SESSION['sides']` each time round the loop

So concatenate the value like this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['sides'])) {
        foreach($_POST['sides'] as $check) {
            $_SESSION['sides'] .= $check;
        }
    }
    header('location: show.php');
?>
```

You may like to add a seperator in there as well like this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['sides'])) {
        foreach($_POST['sides'] as $check) {
            $_SESSION['sides'] .= $check . ',';
        }
    }
    rtrim($_SESSION['sides'], ',');  // remove last comma seperator
    header('location: show.php');
?>
```

> Additional Note: Remember that PHP will only get sent the Checked checkbox values.

Comment: You can also use array_push instead of concate string. $_SESSION['sides'][] = $check or array_push(sesionarray, id);

Comment: Yea, I didnt want to make it that complicated. Would require a bit more work in the last page code to get them printed :)